# Cannot resolve symbol A

Tags: scala

I have following trait:

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B]

final case class Failure[A](value: A) extends Sum[A, Nothing]

final case class Success[B](value: B) extends Sum[Nothing, B]

object Sum {

  def flatMap[AA >: A, B, C](s: Sum[AA, B], f: B => Sum[AA, C]): Sum[AA, C] =
    s match {
      case Failure(v) => Failure(v)
      case Success(v) => f(v)
    }

  def fold[A, B, C](s: Sum[A, B], success: A => C, failure: B => C): C =
    s match {
      case Failure(v) => failure(v)
      case Success(v) => success(v)
    }

  def map[A, B, C](s: Sum[A, B], success: A => C): Sum[A,C] =
    fold(s, succ => Success(success(succ)), fail => Failure(fail))

}
```

and the compiler complain:

```
Cannot resolve symbol A
```

by:

```
flatMap[AA >: A, B, C]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it give a line number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're defining a lower bound for a type parameter that doesn't exist. What is `A` in this context? You're telling the compiler "I want AA to have a lower bound of type `A`", but the compiler doesn't know a generic type parameter `A` because it wasn't declared.

If you want to have two type parameter, where one is a lower bound on another (or more generally any bound), it needs to be declared first:

```
def flatMap[A, AA >: A, B, C]
```